How to set timeout for a specific HttpRequestMessage instance in C#? .NET 6
I am using a static singleton HttpClient object where many requests are sent through. How do I set a timeout value for a specific request. I do not want to set it for the HttpClient object and make it the same for all the requests.
class Program {

    private static HttpClient client;

    static Program() {
        client = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler(){
            PooledConnectionLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
        });
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        //request without timeout
        HttpRequestMessage request1 = new(Get, "https://www.google.com");
        var respone1 = client.SendAsync(request1).Result;

        //request with timeout
        HttpRequestMessage request2 = new(Post, "https://www.posttest.com");
        request2.Content = new StringContent("Hello World");
        //set request timeout
        //request2.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); --how to do this?
        try{
            var response2 = client.SendAsync(request2).Result;
        }
        catch(TimeoutException e){
            Console.WriteLine("Request timed out");
        }
    }

}

I am using .NET 6

You can use Polly for this
var pipeline = new ResiliencePipelineBuilder()
   .AddTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
   .Build();
try
{
    response2 = await pipeline.ExecuteAsync(
      async token => await client.SendAsync(request2, token),
      CancellationToken.None);
}
catch (TimeoutRejectedException)
{
   //...
}


Basically you create a Timeout strategy which will use CancellationToken to cancel the pending request if the timeout's threshold is reached
You execute your HttpClient inside the ResiliencePipeline
You have to pass the CancellationToken to the SendAsync call


You can disable the timeout on HttpClient and use a CancellationTokenSource to control the timeout.
client.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;

var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var response2 = client.SendAsync(request1, cts.Token).Result;

